# How to use $t from vue-i18n inside Vuex store to initialize static strings

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuetify.js, vue-i18n

In my vuex store module I have provinceData to supply as datasource for Vuetify dropdown selection box.

```
provinceData:  [
            {value:"AB", text: "Alberta"},
            {value:"BC", text: "British Columbia"},
            ...
        ],
```

I can `import i18n from '../plugins/i18n'` and confirm in console output that `i18n.t('province.BC')` return me proper text from resource files

```
i18n.t('province.BC') British Columbia
click onLanguageChange fr
i18n.t('province.BC') British Columbia (Fr)
```

But how I can insert these translations into datasource?

```
provinceData:  [
            {value:"AB", text: ???i18n.t('province.AB')??? },
            {value:"BC", text: ???i18n.t('province.BC')??? },
            ...
        ]
```

Now I realized what mistake I did by wrapping i18n.t('province.AB') into back ticks. Here is corrected version which render english only messages:

```
provinceData:  [
            {value:"AB", text: i18n.t('province.AB') },
            {value:"BC", text: i18n.t('province.BC') },
            ...
        ]
```

Moreover, will it be reinitialized if I switch the current locale?

PS. When getter for this datasource is hit I can see that message retrieved according to current locale. But dropdown box izn't reloaded. That's the problem

Following getter print correct translation every time it called:

```
provinceData: (state) => {
            console.log("i18n.t('province.BC')",i18n.t('province.BC'));
            return state.provinceData;
        },
```

Comment: Use `this.$i18n.t(...` when initializing it within data.

Comment: Now I realized what mistake I did by wrapping i18n.t('province.AB') into quotes and astericks. But 2nd question still exists: How static data will reload on change locale?

Comment: I feel like it should be in getter, so when you access data it'll be according to correct language

Comment: do you mean I have to reload datasource when getter is hit? I've updated the post.

Answer (score 0):

Because the provinceData inside the store it can't be modified by anything but mutators.
So I decided to create this array right in the getter and it turns out to be quite fast.

```
provinceData: ( state ) =>
        {
            const provinceData = [ "AB", "BC", "MB", "NB", "NF", "NT", "NS", "NU", "ON", "PE", "QC", "SK", "YT" ];
            let provinces = [];

            provinceData.forEach( (province) => {
                provinces.push
                ({
                    value : province,
                    text  : i18n.t( 'province.'+province )
                })
            })

            return provinces;
        }
```